# Windows 10 tcp timed out

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping, tcp

Few time ago my notebook with win 10 started behaving strange. My Google Chrome always give me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT for something about 5 or 10 minutes and then start to work normally. I've also tried to install Firefox and got the same problem there. After googling I found solutions like `ifconfig /flushdns` but it didn't help.
 I've tried `netsh winsock reset` and it didn't help me too. Finally, switching WiFi on and off, setting Google dns in parameters and  installing netcat gave me no result. And the strange thing is that ping is always working fine both with ip and with url, so it looks like dns works fine. I have such a problem on two notebooks with win 10

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well.  I've tried changing the Power Options to High Performace in the control panel, disabled Green Ethernet amd Energy Efficient ethernet from network adapters in Device Manager, changed registry setting for LanManServer and LanManWorkstation to stay active for hours, and even changed cables amd routers. All Windows updates done, drivers up to date, no error in Event Viewer. I'm stuck, too...